# Why I get error on dependency when it added to pom file?

Tags: java, spring, maven

On this I am using java spring project.
I am new to java spring so maybe my question will be silly.
I am adding dependebcy to pom.xml file in my project, but get error on the added dependency.

Here is pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.MichaelTutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>conference-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>conference-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>c
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here the dependency that I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

On this org.postgresql and postgresql I get same error:

```
Dependency 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.19' not found
```

Any idea how to fix it? why version does not found?

Comment: Please try deleting the org/postgresql/postgresql directory from your local repo, to force maven to download the dependency again, and post the entire log.

Comment: Try running ‘man clean install’ either in you IDE or from command line in root folder of ur project

Comment: try `mvn clean package -U` this will force to redownload dependencies